# term does not evaluate to a function taking 0 arguments

Tags: c++

I had try to compile this code but it shows this error "term does not evaluate to a function taking 0 arguments"

I'm completely new to programming so please help me out here.

For reference, the problem function seems to be:

```
void traps_rand()
{

    while (player!=treasure)
      srand((unsigned)time(0));

    xt1=(rand %6()+1);
    xt2=(rand %6()+1);
    xt3=(rand %6()+1);
    yt1=(rand %8()+1);
    yt2=(rand %8()+1);
    yt3=(rand %8()+1);
...
...
...
```

Comment: how do you compile your code ? can you include the error message that made you decide that the included code contains the error ?

Comment: term does not evaluate to a function taking 0 arguments

Comment: Is this C++ or C? Pick one. Please don't use irrelevant tags as it is annoying for people trying to search for questions with specific tags. Look through your code *carefully*. If you still can't see your problem, you need to review the basics on how to call a function.

Comment: http://codepad.org/UKVjhZMb This is the full code

Comment: What does this mean `rand %6()+1`? It looks like a term trying to evaluate to a function taking 0 arguments.

Comment: I'm sorry, it's my first time asking questions online

Comment: You should consider using the facilities in the `<random>` library instead of outdated and bad C functions.

Comment: As the other commenters mentioned, it would help to (1) include the entire function (or if possible file) that's causing you problems and (2) if you provide as much of the compiler output as you can.  I suggested an edit, but you may want to make a further edit where you include the entire problem function or (if it's not huge) file.

Answer (score 4):

I'm pretty sure this is what you want if you are trying to generate a random number between 1-6:

```
xt1 = rand() % 6 + 1;
```

The statement above executes the function `rand` (as noted by the parentheses), then does modulo 6 on the result before adding 1.

Your original statement:

```
xt1=(rand %6()+1);
```

is attempting to invoke the function "6" and use that as the modulus with the address of rand.  Then add 1.  It hits as error because there is no function named 6.  You can't name functions starting with numbers anyway.

Comment: Thanks!! I'm sorry if it's been so obvious but I really am just starting to learn c++ and it's my first time learning a programming language, Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3):

Change `rand %6()+1` to `rand() %6 + 1`. It looks like you are using a variable named `rand` and calling a function named `6()`, but what you really want is to call `rand()` and mod it by 6 (+1).